# How do I port a .FON font to a Linux font?

Tags: fonts

I like the ProggyClean fonts a lot and would like to see them in my terminal. The "True Type Font" versions aren't great, but the bitmap (raster, *.fon) fonts are excellent. This should be a virtue since the Linux fonts are all raster as a matter of course.

I think the Linux font format is PSF2 (among others?) and is detailed here: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/font-formats-1.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the [LinuxFont](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxfont/) project?

Its purpose is to create PSF2 fonts, and it has a way to convert `.fon` font files.

Answer (score 1):

You can download bitmap Proggy fonts from [ProggyFonts.com](http://www.proggyfonts.com/index.php?menu=download).

In any case install and use **FontForge**. Load a .fon file and save as .sfd.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't see "sfd" in `man setfont`; does linux use sfd files? Perhaps there is some sfd -> psf2 converter?

Comment: @LimitedAtonement: SFD is Fontforge's native file-format, analogous to Gimp's native XCF.  You must export the font from Fontforge, to get the final product.  SFD files are great for saving a work in progress, I would also recommend you save one right before your final export.  So if you ever need to go back, as creating correct PSF/PSF2 is not trivial, you won't need to recreate all your work.