# How can I install Windows font format (.FNT, .FON) in Linux

Tags: fonts, font-manager

I am working on some research related to FreeType2 Driver modules. I started my study by reading the Windows font Driver module (Because of its simplicity compared to TrueType and Type1). This Driver module works when a file with format `.FNT` or `.FON` is inputed from client application.

So, as a first step I want to install some windows font of extension `.FNT` or.FON. After searching for quite a long time I figured out that `.FNT` is not used any more in windows so I can't download it. `.FON` format is used in windows 10 its a raster type font. So I decided to copy this file (Fro windows fonts folder) to my `/usr/share/FON/` directory. It copied successfully and its icon was like an executable file in Linux but when I used fontconfig for updating with fc-cache and than listing with fc-list I couldn't see that.

So, is there a way I can install them and test my Windows Driver module? I know how to install normal `.ttf` fonts and use them, I am asking about .FON, `.FNT` format of windows fonts.

Comment: @Yaron are u kidding me? i mean i know how to install fonts in linux. iam asking how install specific format of font files.

Comment: You should find the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/q/205969/544264

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I port a .FON font to a Linux font?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/205969/how-do-i-port-a-fon-font-to-a-linux-font)

Comment: @Yaron This is about converting .FON to other format. In my case i need same format and pass it to FreeType

Comment: @Melebius Please read my question and comments